# Плавная анимация для подложки бокового меню

Tags: css, bootstrap, transition, sidebar

Всех приветствую.

Реализовываю боковое меню вот из этого примера: https://blog-kopilka.ru/demo_html/bootstrap4-sidebar/index.php

Не получается решить вопрос со скоростью появления/исчезновения полупрозрачной подложки, когда открывается/закрывается боковое меню.

В примере код, отвечающий за подложку, выглядит так:

```
.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 998;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay.active {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Я понимаю, что свойство, отвечающее за скорость анимации является **transition**. Однако, как бы я не менял время данного свойства, появление/исчезновение подложки анимируется мгновенно. Выглядит это очень резко.

Буду признателен за пояснение причин, из-за которых свойство **transition** не работает у данного элемента. А также за рекомендации, как можно реализовать поставленную задачу и сделать появление/исчезновение подложки плавным.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит отказаться от использование `display` так как они прерывает вашу анимацию. Только `opacity` вам тоже не поможет, так как элемент все еще находиться в области видимости и не будет пропускать некоторые события например клик на элементы стоящие ниже по `z-index`. Для того что бы пропустить клик на элементы который находятся ниже по `z-index` вас стоит использовать другие свойства. Например: `visibility` в паре с `opacity`.

Пример кода:

```
  .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0.5s, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .overlay.active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: visible 0.5, opacity 0.5s ease-in;
  }
```

Пример песочницы: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-water-rcmro?file=/index.html:111-515

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Ваш вариант отлично работает.

Answer (score 2):

display block; и display none; не берут свойство transition что бы случилось, так что можешь дерзать так или с помощю библиотеки jQuery

```css
.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 998;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    animation: anim 1s ease;
}

@keyframes anim{
  0%{display:block;}
  10%{opacity:0;}
  100%{opacity:1;}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения и предложения. Несмотря на то, что я предпочел вариант, в котором предложили полностью отказаться от свойства display и заменить его на visibility, полезно иметь альтернативу. Еще раз благодарю.